# JavaScript changing content dynamically using a delay

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have an array of values that I am passing to a JavaScript function. I would like the function to loop through the array and update a div every 15 seconds to display the new value. I have written the code below. Unfortunatly, the DOM is frozen until the script completes. I am trying to create a sudo slide show effect. Is there an alternate wait function I can use that is asynchronous.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    runDisplay();
});
    
function runDisplay() {

var rotations = 2;  
var teams = '1,4,2,3';

var res = teams.split(",");
var arrayLength = res.length;
var r = 0;  
//Do until max rotations
do {
    

//loop through team array
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    //update team display 
    document.getElementById("TeamDisplay").innerHTML=res[i];
    wait(7000); 
    }
    //increment rotations
    r = r + 1;
    } while (r <= rotations);   
    
    //refresh page after rotations are complete
    
    }
    
    function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
    }
    }
```

Comment: don't use a "busy wait" like this - it stops anything else from happening! Look up `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Comment: How would I use setInterval() within the for loop of the runDisplay function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use setInterval or setTimout functions.

Here is an example with setTimeout

```js
var rotations = 2;  
var teams = '1,4,2,3';

var res = teams.split(",");
var arrayLength = res.length;
var r = 0;  
var i = 0;

function loop() {
    if(r < rotations){
        
        if (i < arrayLength) {
            document.getElementById("TeamDisplay").innerHTML=res[i];
            setTimeout(loop, 7000);  
            i++;
        }
        
        else {
          r++;
          i = 0;
          loop();
        }
    }
}

loop();
```

```html
<div id="TeamDisplay"></div>
```